# Google Cloud Datastore Python Library - force entity property to TextProperty instead of bytes?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the Google cloud datastore library for python, the one that you get by doing `from google.cloud import datastore` (sorry I can't be more specific, I know there are like 3 or 4 different libraries including `ndb`). The issue is that when I'm trying to save a TextProperty it ends up being a BytesProperty as base64 encoded data. Code below

```
    from google.cloud import datastore
    expiration_date = plan.get('expiration_date')
    ds = datastore.Client()
    dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    key_str= "%s:%s:%s" % (user_id, camera_id, dt.isoformat())
    complete_key = ds.key('RollingPlanCounter', key_str)
    rolling_counter = datastore.Entity(key=complete_key, exclude_from_indexes=['byte_counts'])
    byte_counts = json.dumps({
        'upload_bytes_total': 0,
        'movie_bytes_total': 0,
        'event_bytes_total': 0,
        'upload_bytes_total_important': 0,
        'movie_bytes_total_important': 0,
        'event_bytes_total_important': 0
    })
    rolling_counter.update({
        "user_id": user_id,
        "camera_id": camera_id,
        "creation_date": dt,
        "expiration_date": expiration_date,
        "byte_counts": str(byte_counts)
    })
```

But when I look in datastore I see this

[image: base64 data]

How do I have a 'hint' to the library that this should be a TextProperty and not a Bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/usage.html#module-google.cloud.datastore), specifically this part

> Note Property values which are “text” (‘unicode’ in Python2, ‘str’ in
>   Python3) map to ‘string_value’ in the datastore; values which are
>   “bytes” (‘str’ in Python2, ‘bytes’ in Python3) map to ‘blob_value’.

You need to cast to cast to unicode for it to know to have it be a TextProperty. So all I had to do was this

```
    byte_counts = json.dumps({
        'upload_bytes_total': 0,
        'movie_bytes_total': 0,
        'event_bytes_total': 0,
        'upload_bytes_total_important': 0,
        'movie_bytes_total_important': 0,
        'event_bytes_total_important': 0
        'events_important_count': 0,
        'movies_important_count': 0
        'movies_discarded_count': 0
    })
    rolling_counter.update({
        "user_id": user_id,
        "camera_id": camera_id,
        "creation_date": dt,
        "expiration_date": expiration_date,
        "byte_counts": unicode(byte_counts, "utf-8") # <-- here
    })
```

and the datastore now shows that they're being stored as text property.

Comment: actually - they're being stored as StringProperty, which is a pain in the ass as strings are extremely limited in size. There is currently no means of getting it to be stored as a TextProperty using this module, only StringProperty and Blob

Comment: I ran into the same thing, and checked the library source. In site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/proto/entity.proto the API protocol is defined (it is using protobuf). And from there it is evident that the protocol only supports string and blob, so there is no hope to add support for TextProperty on the python client library side unfortunately.